# matching ID when expanding list of vectors to data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that consists of an ID and a column containing a list of vectors for each row. So kind of like this except I put "list of vectors" in the column for simplicitys sake:

```
   id           lists
1 123 list of vectors
2 345 list of vectors
3 456 list of vectors
4 789 list of vectors
```

After expanding each list into a data.frame and appending, the result of the lists column into a data.frame looks like this:

```
  att1 att2 run
1  600   43   a
2  500   34   b
3  300   54   a
4  300   34   b
5  250   34   a
6  360   34   b
7  700   23   a
8  750   12   b
```

What I'd like to do is then include a first column with which id each row belongs to. In this case, each id should have two runs, so I know I can do rep(dt[,1],each=2) to get this:

```
   id att1 att2 run
1 123  600   43   a
2 123  500   34   b
3 345  300   54   a
4 345  300   34   b
5 456  250   34   a
6 456  360   34   b
7 789  700   23   a
8 789  750   12   b
```

but I'd really like a better way to do this in the case where the runs vary for each id. (3 runs for one id, 7 runs for another, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear about the structure.  Assuming the `lists` is a `list` of `list`s, then

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  pull(lists) %>%
  set_names(df1$id) %>%
  map_df(data.frame, .id = 'id')
```

Comment: yeah sorry, so the list column has a list structure where one row looks like this (600,500,43,34,a,b) and for the second row it would be (300,300,54,34,a,b). To convert it into a data.frame I use as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, dt[,2])).

Comment: @aabernathy  Is it a `list` or `vector`  I meant `list(600, 500, 43, 34, "a", "b")` or `c(600, 500, 43, 34, "a", "b")` the second case results in a `character` vector

Comment: @aabernathy  Did you meant somehting like this `df1 <- data.frame(id = c(123, 345), lists = I(list(list(att1 = c(600, 500), att2 = c(43, 34), run = c("a", "b")), list(att1 = c(300, 300), att2 = c(54, 34), run = c("a", "b")))))`

Comment: column 'lists' has class list in r

Comment: yeah, thats what I meant

Comment: @aabernathy  If that is the case, the code should work